# How to replace the whole entity list in many-to-many relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```cs
public async Task UpdateEntity(EntityModel update)
{
    _context.AttachRange(update.Links);
    _condext.Update(update);
}
```

In this example, I have many-to-many relation between `EntityModel` and `LinkModel`. The instance `update` is not attached to the context and has a list of `LinkModel` entities with added and removed rows. I want to update the whole list of linked elements in one request to database without comparing added and deleted rows. Is that possible?

Code in the example is working when adding linked elements the first time, but then throws an error about already existing elements in table "EntitiesLinksRelations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to fetch the existing entity with its related links first -

```cs
public async Task UpdateEntity(EntityModel update)
{
    _context.AttachRange(update.Links);

    var existingEntity = _context.EntityModels
                        .Include(p => p.Links)
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == update.Id);            

    existingEntity.Links.Clear();
    foreach (var link in update.Links)
    {
        existingEntity.Links.Add(link);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**EDIT - A bit of clarification**

The code above does not -

1. delete *all* the existing linking data (data from the joining table)
2. then insert new ones for *all* related data in the new list

as it might seem at the first glance, specifically because of the statement - `existingEntity.Links.Clear();`

How much data gets deleted or inserted depends on the data in the new list (`update.Links`). For example, if the existing `EntityModel` had 100 related `LinkModel`, and in the new list 50 of them had been removed and 20 new ones had been added, the code above -

1. loads all 100 related `LinkModel`
2. generates delete command for the removed 50 `LinkModel`
3. generates insert command for the added 20 `LinkModel`

Comment: Note that this might become very resource intensive if the collection you are replacing is very large, so use this pattern with caution, for instance this is not advised to purge logs or other similarly long or open-ended collections.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller At which point exactly - attaching the received entities to the context, fetching the existing entity with related data, or something else? Also, for many-to-many scenario can you suggest a better alternative to avoid that, if the collection is very large?

Comment: At `.FirstOrDefault()` _All_ of the included links are loaded into memory, depending on the number of includes or the complexity of the projection, this can have negative and unexpected side effects. For simple scenarios, you won't notice a difference, but IMO this is a bad habbit to develop without understanding the potential impact. The workaround is different in .Net FX and Core

Comment: I can suggest an alternative, but not during office hours... ;)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Its fetching an entity with related data, so there is no _complexity of the projection_ here. Any loaded data is stored in-memory, there's nothing new to know about this. And for many-to-many relation either you have to compare with the _all_ existing related data and add/remove based on that comparison, or you have to clear _all_ the existing related data add the new ones. In both case You need _all_ related data in-memory.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I'll check for your alternative, after your office hour...  ;)

Comment: Not disputing the fact it needs to be cleared, but if there are 1000s or maybe millions of records, there is no need to load all of these into memory so EF can delete them one by one in `SaveChanges`. The loading, subsequent delete commands and implicit transaction scopes can cause all sorts of unexpected side effects like timeouts, deadlocks, memory overflows, and network congestion. With projections or multiple levels of include this becomes especially problematic. So while it seems like a quick fix, it is not good generic advice without strong words of caution, which is where I come in.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller "_if there are 1000s or maybe millions of records_" then I'd create a stored procedure and handle the operation on database end. But that argument holds against EF/Core in general, not against any specific solution using EF/Core.

Comment: SP is a bit overkill, but you can do it that way. In FX you MUST do it via SQL, in Core there are some better work arounds. It's just important to note that loading data into the context specifically to delete those records is an antipattern that should be avoided, or at least not encouraged in forums where noobs will hold only this for the rest of their careers